# How can I automate a webview in Android

Tags: android, selenium, webview

I have a WebView in my android app that opens up a page I would like to automate. How can I automate it so that it fills out the form and does a bunch of other similar tasks? I used selenium and python to do it on my laptop, but I have no clue as to how to get it working inside of a webview. Sort of like a bing rewards bot or something except that's not exactly what I'm making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by enabling Javascript in your webview and adding a Javascript interface to your webview. You'll end up with Javascript functions embedded in your app that you execute via Java methods. The whole process is explained in detail here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#UsingJavaScript

Comment: Can I automate a couple of forms selenium style? I used selenium to fill the forms out on my laptop, so I was wondering if this works here?

Comment: Yeah absolutely. You can perform all the button clicks/filling out of fields/submitting forms etc in JS, then listen for webview navigation events from your Java code.

Comment: Wait I have one more question. I see this is possible if it's a web page I made, but in this case it's not. I want to fill out a form made by someone else on a webpage whose source I do not have access to. How would I do something like this?

Comment: You would inject the Javascript into the page and execute it using the loadUrl method of WebView. Something like this: `mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('btn1').click();");`

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to get this to work, but it's been just a waste of time. I haven't gotten anywhere and I'm not sure why It's not working. I used the code snipped you gave me, but the webview won't fill out the form!!!

Comment: I'm sorry it's not working for you. Perhaps I can help if you post some code

Comment: Yeah good point. I'll make sure to do that later today when I get a chance.

Comment: Alright so I have the link for it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379078/how-can-i-fill-out-a-form-using-javascript-on-android). I asked the question a couple of days ago to no avail. Maybe you can help.