# How can I fill out a form using Javascript on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, forms, webview

Alright, so I'm working on an app that will fill out forms. I have no idea how to do this, other than the fact that I need to use Javascript for this. This code loads the web page, but does not input any values to the form.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        WebView myWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        myWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                WebView myWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

                //hide loading image
                findViewById(R.id.progress).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //show WebView
                findViewById(R.id.webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });
        myWebview.loadUrl("https://www.panerabread.com/en-us/mypanera/registration-page.html");
        myWebview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(\"join_first_name\").value=\"Hello World\";");
    }
```

Below is my second class. Not sure what this does, I got it from the documentation though.

```
    public class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the loadUrl("javascript..." into the onPageFinished listener. You're calling it before the page is loaded.

Comment: Ok, so we're making progress. Instead of filling out the form, it brings up another page with the words "Hello World". So it's doing something, just not what I want it to do :'(

Comment: Hmm... I think any js you inject needs to not return a value. It looks like this person got around it by adding void(0). http://stackoverflow.com/a/27551727/5482166

Comment: IT WORKS! IT REALLY WORKS! :DDDDDD